# WebStorm remote Node.js interpreter not stopping script

Tags: node.js, webstorm, interpreter

I have set up remote node.js interpreter in WebStorm IDE. I can start remote script, but restart (or stop and start) informing me about already used port (what means old instance of script still runs). I changed my dedicated server recently and on old everything was working ok. Now its broken.

What I am doing bad?